# Rails 3 conditional expression retirns nil is it issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

ruby-1.9.3-p194
Rails 3.0.9

I encountered so much strange behavior of conditional expression evaluation.
Look at piece of code:

```
module SimpleCaptcha
  module ControllerHelpers
    def simple_captcha_valid?

      t = Logger.new(STDOUT)

      return true if Rails.env.test?

      if params[:captcha]
        data = 'SHGHGD'
        result = data == params[:captcha].delete(" ").upcase

        t.debug data
        t.debug params[:captcha].delete(" ").upcase
        t.debug result

      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what I see in debug console:

```
SHGHGD
WEWE
nil
```

As you can see nil is a result of evaluation **result = data == params[:captcha].delete(" ").upcase**

But why???
**data** is **'SHGHGD'**
**params[:captcha].delete(" ").upcase** is **WEWE**

Why nil? it must be false.

Comment: If you try `t.debug result.to_s` does that work?

Comment: t.debug result.to_s returns false as I expect but false is instance of StringClass but not FalseClass.

Comment: FalseClass.to_s should return StringClass "false", NilClass.to_s should return an empty StringClass "".  Try your scenario here to see if the results are the same: http://tryruby.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually because of the logger - `Logger.debug false` outputs nil. To understand why you need to look into the logger class (logger.rb). The debug, info, warn etc. methods all end up calling

```
def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
  severity ||= UNKNOWN
  if @logdev.nil? or severity < @level
    return true
  end
  progname ||= @progname
  if message.nil?
    if block_given?
      message = yield
    else
      message = progname
      progname = @progname
    end
  end
end
```

and message will be nil, progname will be the value you've passed (ie a string). The keyline is `progname ||= @progname`. Because progname is `false`, it is overwritten with the value of `@progname`, which is nil so that is what gets output.